# Should there be a [cs50] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

At this moment, there are 100 [c](/questions/tagged/c) questions that refer to Harvard's cs50 course.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+cs50

Is that enough to warrant its own tag? Or is it too similar to the ill-fated [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag?

---

Edit: An additional reason I didn't think of until downvoted (and defensive): When combined with the [c](/questions/tagged/c)-tag, it would identify the [non-standard library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) that is typically used, and potentially spare tender n00bs from undue harassment about things like

```
typedef char *string;
```

exhibited in these questions:
[Reading file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444944/reading-file-in-c)
[Program that checks for a negative argv not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781339/beginner-c-program-that-checks-for-a-negative-argv-not-working/19781391#19781391)
[What is wrong in this implementation of Caesar Cipher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744557/what-is-wrong-in-this-implementation-of-caesar-cipher)
[Why am I getting a warning 'Segementation fault, core dumped' in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707026/why-am-i-getting-a-warning-segementation-fault-core-dumped-in-c)
[Segmentation fault in my Vigenere encryption program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321668/segmentation-fault-in-my-vigenere-encryption-program-c)
[crypt() function in C not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311397/crypt-function-in-c-not-working)
[warning: implicit declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213109/warning-implicit-declaration)
[Repetition using switch statement inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485435/repetition-using-switch-statement-inside-a-for-loop)
[Using a returned value from a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640606/using-a-returned-value-from-a-function-in-c)

Edit: There is also precedent set by the existence of this tag: [learn-c-the-hard-way](/questions/tagged/learn-c-the-hard-way). **Edit: tag has been depopulated.**

Edit: Just discovered that a cs50x site is in private beta, now!
https://cs50.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f

Comment: @Downvoter, Is this such a bad question? Am I wasting your precious time?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). A user may have shown her/his disagreement on creating [cs50] tag by downvoting. Don't sweat, its not a bad question tough.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Understood. Thanks again.

Comment: I really don't get why we need to downvote this. It makes sense for a feature request (sorta), but downvoting discussion seems… strange. It's a perfectly valid discussion that does not warrant negative reputation.

Comment: @bjb568 Using their down votes, 7 users said "no" to the question asked in the post title: "Should there be a [cs50] tag?" I think it is perfectly fine.

Comment: 7 users were too lazy to either write a response or vote up the existing answer.

Comment: To be fair, take a look at revision 1 of the question, which is how it looked when most of the downvotes happened. I had not put in so much effort at that point. There were no links to harsh comments to noobs, no argument besides "there are >100 of these questions". ... Perhaps the lesson is: *don't put the question in the title!*

Comment: Can this be migrated to Meta SO?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 It's probably too old to migrate. But the issue can be raised again on meta SO if it's still relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that enough to warrant its own tag?

I would say **no**. Help center has this content about **what are tags**:

- A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.
- Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

For example, if there is a question with just one tag ([cs50]), would a user be able to identify the topic/subject of the question using this tag? Also will this tag be able to connect this question with the experts of this topic? Experts of [cs50]! Answers to both these questions will most probably be "no".

[cs50] will not be a useful tag as tags at Stack Exchange are not designed to categorize questions by a specific book, course, or person.

Comment: I see. I suppose it would be a meta-tag.